# Adding straight quote marks to \texttt

Tags: punctuation

**Problem:**

Inline text gets curled quote marks and I would like to format these automatically to be straight ones instead.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

The function \code{date('Y-m-d')} allows you to...

\end{document}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

Instead of curled single quotes, they should be straight ones like `'`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

One option is to use the `\textquotesingle` from the `textcomp` package as this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

The function \code{date(\textquotesingle Y-m-d\textquotesingle)} allows you to...

\end{document}
```