# Changing all single quotes to be straight when within texttt

Tags: typewriter

I have a document with many `'` characters inside of `texttt`. Is there a way to make them all appear straight when in `texttt`?

I know that I can search/replace all `'` with `\textquotesingle`:

- [Adding straight quote marks to \texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257612/adding-straight-quote-marks-to-texttt)
- [Straight quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52529/straight-quotes)
- [Typesetting single quotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50533/typesetting-single-quotes)

Perhaps there is some preamble declaration to tell `texttt` to render all `'` as `\textquotesingle`?

Comment: Did you know that LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX both typeset straight single quotes (apostrophes) automatically whenever a monospaced font is in use (as is the case with the argument of `\texttt`)? I've posted an answer to elaborate on this observation.

Comment: For which versions of (Xe/Lua)LaTeX is this known to work?

Comment: It certainly works for the current versions, i.e., the ones distributed with TeXLive2018. I believe it's been working like this for quite some time, but I don't have access to older TeX distributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach using active characters, but still allowing `\texttt` usage inside arguments of other macros. (because it uses `\scantokens`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for robustify

\robustify{\texttt}
\let\originaltexttt\texttt

\begingroup
\catcode`'=\active
\catcode``=\active
\globaldefs1
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd{\texttt}[1]{%
   {%
   \everyeof{\noexpand}\endlinechar-1
   \expandafter\catcode\string``=\active
   \expandafter\catcode\string`'=\active
   \let'\textquotesingle
   \let`\textasciigrave
   \ifx\encodingdefault\upquote@OTone
    \ifx\ttdefault\upquote@cmtt
     \def'{\char13 }\def`{\char18 }%
    \fi
   \fi
   \scantokens{\originaltexttt{#1}}%
   }%
}%
\endgroup


\begin{document}

\null\vfill
abc'def---\texttt{abc'def}---abc'def 
\footnote{\texttt{This is a footnote ``''}}

\textit{\texttt{abc`def'ghi}}---\texttt{\textit{abc`def'ghi}}
\footnote{\textit{\texttt{This is another footnote ``''}}}

\end{document}
```

The advantage compared to [my other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436347/4686) is that it makes do with the document typewriter font, it does not modify it. The disadvantage is that `\scantokens` may reserve some surprises. Concretely the main issue coming to my mind is that one should not use it in a context where the space character has been made active, and the main case will be the [`alltt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/alltt) environment (of course `verbatim` is no issue, as `\texttt` macro does not get executed). But that's already a bit specialized context, so generally speaking it will be fine.

[image]

Notice that my approach loads package [`upquote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/upquote) so verbatim environment will be with straight single quotes too.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yours already was `:)`.

Comment: Though a pity our relative scores don't reflect that (yet!)

Comment: in my text I wanted to say one could not use `\texttt`  inside `alltt` environment... I did not want to say one could not use `alltt` environment! And who would use `\texttt` inside `alltt` which, as its name indicates is already using typewriter? `:) `. (now that I think about it...)

Answer (score 11):

Here I redefine `\texttt` to make `'` active and replace itself with `\textquotesingle`.  The original definition is saved in `\svtexttt`.

EDITED to return `'` to non-active status at the conclusion of a `\texttt`.

REEDITED to use `letltxmacro`, per egreg's suggestion.

REREEDITED to restore the originally defined `'` after `\texttt` usage, so as not to interfere with math conversion to `\prime` (hat tip/mumbled curse to David).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp,lmodern,letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\svtexttt}{\texttt}
\catcode`'=\active %
\let\svprime'
\renewcommand\texttt{\catcode`'=\active \def'{\textquotesingle}\textttaux}
\newcommand\textttaux[1]{\svtexttt{#1}\gdef'{\svprime}\catcode`'=12 }
\catcode`'=12 %
\begin{document}
\svtexttt{That's life!}

versus

\texttt{That's life!}

Is ' active? No. 

Testing prime: $x' =dx/dt$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With this code ' is active also *after*  the \texttt. Try `Ups' \texttt{That's life!} Ups'`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Thank you for pointing that out.  Fixed.

Comment: Remember about `letltxmacro`.

Comment: @egreg The fact that you mention it means I should adapt to it.  Does that help protect me against moving arguments or something?

Comment: @egre, I see...https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro

Comment: You could ask @UlrikeFischer to confirm my sums: `Is ' active? No. $x' =dx/dt$`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What the heck just happened?  Did you bewitch my code?

Comment: Is it possible to have this method work for `\textbf{\texttt{'a'}}`?

Comment: @jmlarson  No, it can only work as `\texttt{\textbf{'a'}}`, but not the reverse.  This was stated by egreg in his answer: "You could make `'` active, but this has the big disadvantage that `\texttt` can no longer be used in the argument to another command."  The reason is that the `catcode` of a token inside an argument gets permanently assigned as the argument is first digested.  Thus, in your example, as part of the argument to `\textbf`, the `'` will be locked in as `\catcode=12`.

Comment: @jfbu Thanks for such tips,but alas, I have no `\scantokens` experience to speak of, much less expertise.

Answer (score 8):

You could make `'` active, but this has the big disadvantage that `\texttt` can no longer be used in the argument to another command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for robustify

\robustify\texttt

\let\originaltexttt\texttt
\newcommand\activatestraightquote{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`'
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\textquotesingle
  \catcode`'=\active
}
\renewrobustcmd{\texttt}{%
  \begingroup\activatestraightquote
  \innertexttt
}
\newcommand{\innertexttt}[1]{\originaltexttt{#1}\endgroup}

\begin{document}

abc'def \texttt{abc'def} abc'def

\end{document}
```

[image]

A solution that's free from this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\texttt}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_jmlarson_texttt_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ' } { \c{textquotesingle} } \l_jmlarson_texttt_tl
  \ttfamily
  \tl_use:N \l_jmlarson_texttt_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section{abc'def \texttt{abc'def} abc'def}

abc'def \texttt{abc'def} abc'def

\end{document}
```

This can also be extended so as to treat also `"` and `''`.

[image]

Comment: Ah yes...the argument within an argument problem of catcodes.

Comment: I receive an `undefined control sequence` error when I run this example in pdflatex and latex

! Undefined control sequence.
\texttt ...n_texttt_tl {#1}\regex_replace_all:nnN 
                                                  {'}{\c {textquotesingle}}\...
l.20 \section{abc'def \texttt{abc'def} abc'def}

Comment: @jmlarson Are you loading `textcomp`?

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted (and compiled with pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian))

Comment: @jmlarson You have an outdated TeX distribution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use package [`newtxtt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtxtt) with option `straightquotes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[straightquotes]{newtxtt}

\begin{document}

\section{abc'def \texttt{abc'def} abc'def}

abc'def \texttt{abc'def} abc'def

\texttt{`xyz', ``xyz'', "xyz"}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This method, by essence, replaces completely the typewriter font, naturally. In the example above it seems to fit not so bad with default serif font.

Comment: Does not work for me, using `xelatex`. `'` becomes `’`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that works with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. Do examine the code below the screenshot: you'll notice that *absolutely nothing* needs to be done to achieve the desired outcome. This is because LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX use "straight" apostrophes (single quotes) *automatically* if a monospaced font is in use (as is the case with `\texttt`). This is true regardless of whether or not the `fontspec` package is loaded.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex   %% or xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{abc'def \texttt{abc'def} abc'def}

abc'def \texttt {abc'def} abc'def
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not result in straightquotes for XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)

Comment: Same as @jmlarson. Not sure what other font settings could be messing with this?

Comment: @Domi - Thanks. I currently use MacTeX2022. With both `XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994` and `LuaHBTeX 1.15.0`, I can re-create the above screenshot, which I originally posted more than 4 years ago, exactly,  *viz*. "straight" quotes when using `'` (single apostrophe) while in `\texttt` mode. No idea why it's not working on other systems/TeX distributions.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for following up. I ended up using the rather restrictive hackfix posted [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436315/42141). Frustrating, to say the least, that simple things cannot just easily work or be understood across different settings and setups. Maybe there is some `fontspec` interference? Or maybe it has to do with the fact that I also have `setCJKmainfont`, or...? I don't feel like debugging it, but maybe if I have a day or two in the future where I feel like it, I'll apply binary search to find out what the single line is that causes this problem ‍♀️